# htaccess redirect urls ending index.php

Tags: php, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a client with a strange set up. In analytics we are seeing urls getting pageviews that technically dont exist.

**Example:**

```
website.org/questions/search/blog/2016/07/blog-post-name/index.php
```

The current htaccess file looks like this but all that does is redirect these blog urls to the home page.

```
# Redirect index.php Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Is there an htaccess code to create redirects for all urls like this:

**Example:**

```
website.org/questions/search/blog/2016/07/blog-post-name/index.php
```

**to:**

```
 website.org/questions/search/blog/2016/07/blog-post-name
```

Thanks